# Is there a webpage where I can upload apps not application loader

Tags: xcode

Is there a webpage where I can upload apps not application loader. I'm having troubles with application loader and a forum said you can upload via a website. Is it iTunes connect or what? Please provide the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple used to have an upload through the iTunesConnect website, but I think it is no longer available. You now upload either through Application Loader or (easier) through Xcode directly.

The typical workflow is to *build and archive*, then open the organizer in Xcode, select that build you just make, and *submit*.

The most important point is to sign your bundle with your distribution profile that you 
You need to select your **distribution profile**. You might need to import that from the developer portal, if you haven't done so before. You can check on the *Provisioning Profiles* section on the *Devices* page in the Organizer.

Your other question show that this it fails at just this code signing. So a direct upload via a webpage would not help.